# Adding a running total column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a result set from a SQL Server query as below:

**Item Week Amount**

```
1     1      500
1     2     -100
1     3     -200
2     1      800
2     2     -600
2     3     -800
```

What I want to know is, is it possible to derive a fourth column that gives a running total of amount for each item?

My desired result is as follows:

**Item Week Amount Total**

```
1     1      500  500
1     2     -100  400
1     3     -200  200
2     1      800  800
2     2     -600  200 
2     3     -800 -600
```

I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Thanks, i have the same problem.

Comment: I hope you saw the answer below!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `SUM() OVER`

```
SELECT  
      item, 
      week, 
      amount,
      SUM(amount) over (partition by item order by Week) as Total
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: Awesome.. thank you so much. Only thing I had to do was  SUM(Amount) over (partition by item order by Week) as Total

Answer (score 2):

You will need a SQL Server 2012 to support [ROWS PRECEDING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.110).aspx) functions.

```
SELECT  
  item, 
  week, 
  amount,
  SUM(amount) over (partition by item order by Week
       ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
  ) as Total
FROM yourTable
```

http://stevestedman.com/2012/03/rows-preceding-and-following-in-tsql-2012/

Comment: This code works just fine thanks.. but there seems to be a performance degradation when I use the Rows Unbounded Preceding. My query that runs in about 4 seconds is dragged out to 25 seconds.