# How to create a merged cell sub-total in SSRS Matrix Table

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is there a way to create a sub-total that would be in a merged cell.

See the screenshot [image]

Right now, when I add a total, it's positioning on a new cell next to the year.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you please highlight the cells and explain what you want and at what location? I believe the question is not that clear.

Comment: Assuming you are using SQL to return the dataset.. you are better off doing a sum(over) to get the total for each year and then simply display the max for each year here.. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191004/adding-a-running-total-column-in-sql-server