# Get the rolling SUM of one column and bring the result in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, window-functions

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
ID   date           Amount
---------------------------
0    2019-01-25        500
3    2019-02-25       -200
4    2019-02-28        700
5    2019-02-28       -300
```

I want a query that returns the rolling total of the Amount column in an additional column:

```
ID   date           Amount     total amount
--------------------------------------------
0    2019-01-25        500              500
3    2019-02-25       -200              300
4    2019-02-28        700             1000
5    2019-02-28       -300              700
```

This is my query:

```
   SELECT 
       ID,
       TrDate,
       Amount,
       SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT, [Amount])) AS 'total amount'                     
   FROM 
       [Transactions]
```

Comment: I changed your tag. If this actually has something to do with C#, feel free to put the tag back, but please also edit the question to explain how it's relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a running total column in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191004/adding-a-running-total-column-in-sql-server)

Comment: There is no question here.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: **WHY** do you need to do a `CONVERT(FLOAT` on your `Amount` column?? If this is a numerical value, the column **should be** a numerical datatype! Also: I'd strongly recommend using `DECIMAL(p,s)` instead of FLOAT, especially when dealing with money - since `FLOAT` is inherently inaccurate and prone to rounding errors

Answer (score 3):

Use window function `SUM(...) OVER(...)`:

```
SELECT *, SUM(Amount) OVER(ORDER BY id) total_amount FROM mytable;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3fb8c1af66a3ba0acf51e740b7d09cad)**:

```
<pre>
ID | date                | Amount | total_amount
-: | :------------------ | -----: | -----------:
 0 | 25/01/2019 00:00:00 |    500 |          500
 3 | 25/02/2019 00:00:00 |   -200 |          300
 4 | 28/02/2019 00:00:00 |    700 |         1000
 5 | 28/02/2019 00:00:00 |   -300 |          700
</pre>
```

---

NB : if your version of SQLServer does not support window functions, then you can self-join the table and use aggregation:

```
SELECT t.id, t.date, t.amount, SUM(t1.amount) total_amount
FROM mytable t
INNER JOIN mytable t1 ON t1.id <= t.id
GROUP BY t.id, t.date, t.amount
```

Comment: It didn't work I get the result 700  in every single record

Comment: @Master : it is working in the db fiddle that I provided in my answer. Are you copying my query correctly ?

Comment: i'm using sqlserver 2008R2 and as I read order by is working on 2012 and above that's why it didn't work with me

Comment: @Master : I updated my answer with a solution without window functions

Comment: it seems this will work with my query but I couldn't make it any help?

Comment: I added my stored proc above under link (My Stored Proc)