# RunningValue Column

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report that pulls a beginning inventory value and puts it in the header of the report - "Textbox12". Then in the report there is a column that tells me how many of that particular part has shipped out or been received that day and displays that as a total (may be a negative number if we send more out that we get). How do I keep a Running Value where the first row of the report starts with the beginning balance and adds the daily change in inventory? The thing that I cant figure out is how to start with the 'Report Item Value' which represents the daily beginning balance.

```
 My inventory report
```

PART No 1: beginning balance - ***12345*** (Textbox12)

---

**Daily change** | **Total in stock**
+1           **|**    12345+1
-2           **|**    12346-2
0            **|**    12346+0

The daily change expression is also a formula that looks at inbound and outbound columns/values in the report and totals those if that matters.

Comment: would be easier if you can do this in the data source. If you are running SQL server and can modify query - have a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191004/adding-a-running-total-column-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can reference a reportitem from a tablix cell due to the order items are processed. I think the header and footer are done last so you can reference a tablix cell from the header but not the other way around.

You don't say how you get the opening balance but you should be able to copy the expression from Tetxbox12 and use that plus the `RunningValue()` of the `DailyChange` column.

So you would end up with something like this

```
=MyTextBox12Expressionhere 
 + 
 RunningValue(Fields!DailyChange.Value, SUM, "myDataSetName")
```

If this does not help, show a sample of data, the structure of your dataset and the expression in Textbox12 and I can revise the answer.